# VB.net Trying to get text between first and second slashs only

Tags: vb.net, split, backslash

I am trying to retrive the value of the text between the first and second backslashes... but my coding skills have brought me this far and no futher.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim TEST As String = "ONE\TWO\TRHREE\FOR\FIVE"
    Dim splitted = TEST.Split("\"c)
    Dim values = splitted.Skip(1).Take(splitted.Length - 2).ToArray()
    MsgBox(values)
End Sub
```

Comment: So you want `Two` as result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `"Two"` as result, this should be the simplest approach:

```
Dim allToken As String() = "ONE\TWO\TRHREE\FOR\FIVE".Split("\"c)
Dim relevantPart = allToken.Skip(1).Take(1)
Dim result As String = String.Concat(relevantPart) ' "Two"
```

If you don't want a single string but a `String()` use `ToArray`:

```
Dim result As String() = relevantPart.ToArray()
```

Side-Note: you can't output an array directly, you could use `String.Join`:

```
MsgBox(String.Join(", ", result)) ' f.e. comma separated
```

Comment: String.Concat(TextBox22.Text.Split("\"c).Skip(1).Take(1))

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions

```
Dim TEST as String = "ONE\TWO\TRHREE\FOR\FIVE"
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(TEST, "\\(.|\n)*?\\", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Now if you want those values to come out in message boxes

```
For Each ma As Match In matches
    MsgBox(ma.ToString.Trim({"\"c}))
Next
```

This will get you both "TWO" and "FOR". If you want just "TWO" then `matches(0)` is all you need.

Alternatively, if you just want to get the matches into an array in one line, then have each value of the array in a single message box:

```
Dim values = Regex.Matches(TEST, "\\(.|\n)*?\\").Cast(Of Match)().[Select](Function(m) m.Value).ToArray()
MsgBox(String.Join(", ", values))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Split function. It will split on a string and store the separated values in an array. This is the easiest of all the answers here and is probably the most correct way of doing this.

This is the VB way of doing it:

```
Dim s() As String = Split("ONE\TWO\TRHREE\FOR\FIVE", "\")
MessageBox.Show(s(1))
```

And this is the .NET way of doing it:

```
Dim mainString As String = "ONE\TWO\TRHREE\FOR\FIVE"
Dim s() As String = mainString.Split("\")
MessageBox.Show(s(1))
```